# Eclipse Looking for g++ Instead of gcc

Tags: c, eclipse, gcc, makefile

I have the opposite issue compared to most questions I see posted here, and my google-fu has run out.  I'm using Eclipse Luna to work on a C project (on Ubuntu 14.04), with a makefile that I am not allowed to modify. There is no C++ in this project.

The makefile uses the `$(CC)` variable instead of explicitly setting a compiler, and there is no `CC=` or `CC?=` set to anything within the makefile.

Running `make` in terminal works without issue to compile my project, however in Eclipse it says `Program "g++" not found in PATH`.

I set up eclipse to use `make` as the build command and set the toolchain to be "Cross GCC".  I don't have a single c++ file in my project, so why would it be looking for g++ as the default compiler?  Did I miss some detail to set this up, such as adding `CC` as a variable set to something within eclipse?

Comment: is there a rule.make?

Comment: @user3528438 No, not that I know of.

Comment: i'm having the same issue, did you manage to solve your problem?

Comment: @one I did!  I completely forgot to post an answer though.  Gimme a few minutes and I'll post

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the `CC` environment variable was never properly being set anywhere so Eclipse would default it to g++.  In order to fix this follow the below steps:

1. Open the Project's Properties
2. Click on the C/C++ Build option on the left hand side
3. **Uncheck** "Use default build command"
4. Make sure you have a valid build command in the box usually just `make` will do unless you're using other options.
5. Click on the button named 'Variables..."
6. Locate CC and update the value to what it should be.

Here's the documentation where I located this: [help.eclipse.org/luna](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fcdt_u_prop_build_variables.htm)

According to [this forum post](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/443346/) another option is to actually update the command being passed inside of that 'build command' box to `make CC = gcc`, however I've never tested this.